# Hilbert space and group theory: relationship between these two approaches to quantum mechanics, and references for a beginner?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, resource-recommendations, group-theory, mathematics

I have read basic books on Quantum Mechanics like R. Shankar's "Introduction to Quantum Mechanics, Griffiths "Quantum Mechanics" and partly I followed Bransden "Atoms and Molecules".

But none of the above books treat QM in a mathematical way and I am really interested to look into the mathematical side of QM. In doing so, I found a book by Brian C. Hall "**Quantum Mechanics for Mathematicians**," which treats the subject from Hilbert Space approach and another book I found was by Hermann Weyl "**Theory of Groups and Quantum Mechanics**" which treats the subject from group theoretic approach.

What is the relation between those two approaches mentioned above and is there any other book which would deem fit for me who has limited mathematical background?

Comment: In your experience, do you find the Hilbert space concept useful for the description of atoms and molecules?

Comment: I have not learned that much. So I can't comment.

Comment: Then are you sure you want to dive into esoteric mathematics?

Comment: @my2cts i haven't decided to move further down the lane. At present my priority is to start looking into the subject.

Comment: Hall's book is probably too advanced if you have a limited mathematical background. It is a book aimed at graduate students in mathematics withvlimited physical knowledge, but a good mathematical one.

Comment: @my2cts "esoteric" mathematics? There is nothing esoteric about Hilbert spaces or group representations.

Comment: @yuggib i find Peter woit's book which is group theoretical way to QM mentioned in the answer quite fine but what is the relationship between group theoretical approach and Hilbert Space approach?

Comment: There is a point at which useful learning about quantum mechanics can only proceed once you've read up on the requisite mathematics, and the question "I want to read about this fancy QM concept but I don't want to read a math textbook, what do I do?" stops having any answers beyond "gin up and read the math textbooks first". You are quickly approaching that point (if you're not there already).

Comment: In what way is Shankar's book 'not mathematical'? I am reading it currently, and it seems to me to be heavily mathematical.

Comment: @Time4Tea it does not treat hilbert space over which qm is based.

Comment: @RandomXYZ the end of Chapter 1 discusses hilbert spaces and provides an example of their use. Tbh, it seems a bit inconsistent to describe yourself as someone with a 'limited mathematical background', if you find  the math in Shankar's book to be somewhat trivial.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you have a look at Peter Woit's book,

> *Quantum Theory, Groups and Representations: An Introduction* (Springer, 2018).

It's a mathematics book for physicists rather than the other way around. It avoids going too far into esoteric maths while keeping that which is relevant for the typical models of theoretical physics.

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree on this one: this book is a serious waste of paper IMO.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero What is so bad about Woit's book?

Comment: @DanielC I think it gets mired in the math and misses the point.  I'm sure it has its audience (Woit is a serious guy) but for one with "limited mathematical background" as the OP I cannot imagine this being terribly useful.

Comment: So it is not a bad(ly written) book, it is just unsuited for the OP. When you said "serious waste of paper", I immediately thought of Zee's Group Theory book which for me really is a "serious waste of paper".

Comment: @DanielC I don't think Woit's book is great to start with and its greatest virtue is that  you can easily get a pdf and save some trees.  I agree with you that Zee's is missing from my bookself and nobody notices it's missing.

Comment: I didn't get the impression that OP was just at the start. He said he had read the basic books. When I was at a similar stage, (having read Griffiths and Sakurai's books) I found Woit's book very useful for understanding the group theoretical aspects that were barely mentioned during undergraduate courses. At that time, all I could find on group theory were maths books that I perceived as a huge waste of time since I couldn't see the relevance for my interest in QM. Woit's book achieves exactly that, I felt, i.e., presenting group theory in the way that is relevant for QM.

Comment: To each his own my friend.  The mere fact that Woit felt he needed to write a book points to his dissatisfaction with the existing literature.  I don't like it one wee bit but it's clear some do.

Comment: @DavidAce Thank you very much for the wonderful book reference. This book covers group theory part very nicely and mostly works over application of QM rather than foundation of QM "Hilbert space".Can you recommend me which book would be best for that for me.

Answer (score 2):

The best book I can think of for this subject at the moment is [The Quantum Theory of Fields, Volume 1: Foundations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521670535).

I am not recommending you to read quantum field theory. This book contains the best introduction of quantum mechanics in chapter 1 and chapter 2, using rigorous group representation theory in Hilbert space, but is very readable for physicists. It also includes the introduction of [Wigner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem), which plays the key role in quantum mechanics. I learned a great deal of mathematics that is important for understanding quantum physics from this book, such as the mathematical origin of central charge, the mathematical definition of mass in Galilean quantum mechanics. The subject is rarely introduced in other maths and physics textbooks. As for me, the book opened a door to a whole new world of the interactive intertwining of representation theory and quantum physics, such as [Mackey's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Mackey) [induced representation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_representation), which led me to the great book [Theory of Group Representations and Applications](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/0352) by A.O. Barut.

Comment: Barut & Raczka's masterpiece is known to be properly read with a pen and lots of paper aside, since it has some typos.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend

> Anthony Sudbery, *Quantum mechanics and the particles of nature (An outline for mathematicians)*, (Cambridge UP)

As the name implies it is pitched for mathematicians and written by someone with an excellent reputation as mathematical physicist.  It is NOT mathematically formal but does not suffer from the handwaviness of some texts written by physicists.  The target audience is defined by the author as follows:

> "In practice I have imagined this reader as a mathematics student
>   taking a third-year undergraduate course in quantum mechanics such as
>   is commonly offered as a part of the mathematics degree course in
>   British universities".

It remains accessible to a serious reader with interest in a more formal presentation than what is often done.  It does not start with Lie groups (or groups in general) as a topic but connections to group theory are pointed out when needed and it's a good stepping stones to more group-oriented texts.